# log4j syslog remote server

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I'm using spring and log4j and I want to use the SyslogAppender. This is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="syslog" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
        <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL7" />
         <param name="FacilityPrinting" value="true"/>
        <param name="SyslogHost" value="xx.xx.xxx.xx" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss} MYAPP: %-5p %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>



    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="syslog" />
    </root>


</log4j:configuration>
```

But when I look at the syslog server it shows nothings, no file is created. I know the syslog server works cause I tried in from a different server. Tried adding the syslog port but it didn't work

```
<param name="SyslogHost" value="xx.xx.xxx.xx:514" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your syslog is accepting logs from a remote host. Syslog usually listens on 514 port (TCP or UDP). Remote logging is disabled by default on most distributions.

Check:

```
netstat -utn | grep :514
```

Comment: It accepts logs from remote hosts. I can see the new folders with the different hosts ip.

Comment: logger -p local7.notice -n localhost  "testing"

Comment: sorry, stackoverflow allow only edit comments within 5 minutes.

It's hard to guess what is wrong. Use 'logger' to check if syslog is  listening and consuming messages:


`logger -p local7.notice -n PUT.IP.ADDR.HERE  "testing"`


If it works, add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to java command line parameter and see what happen.

Some time ago I've tried SyslogAppender, but switched to  plain old files. Syslogs made stactraces unreadable, and some message were lost under high load.

Comment: I would suggest "netstat -autn | grep :1514" - there are cases where the -s is necessary